# I am confused about Big O notation and the rules

Tags: big-o

I have just learned a little basic stuff about Big O notation and I have been wondering why N^a=O(N^b) if a <=b and why log2 N=O(N^(1/2))?
Does that mean if a function is N^2,we can say it is either O(N^2) or O(N^3)?
I am kinda confused about these.

Also, if there is a function like (2^logN)/(logN)-1/logN, what would the Big O estimate be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Big O is *an upper bound* for the complexity. It should be as tight a fit as possible, but an excessively large upper bound is still an upper bound.

So if you have linear complexity O(N), you also have quadratic complexity O(N^2), even though the latter is a much weaker statement.

> Also, if there is a function like (2^logN)/(logN)-1/logN, what would the Big O estimate be?

`- 1/logN` will never be larger than 1, so effectively constant, and can be ignored.

`2^logN` is linear.

dividing that by `log N` makes it come out at `O(N/log n)`. Sublinear.

Comment: hmm..I kidna get it.But how do you estimate the big O if it is, let's say the example I have, (2^logN)/(logN), is it O(2^n) since 2^n grows much faster?

Comment: Yes, you can say O(2^n), but that would be a rather terrible upper bound. Unless I'm mistaken, it is not even linear complexity.

Comment: why is 2^logN considered linear? Sorry Big O is still very new to me.

Comment: The `log` just undoes the `^`.   `2^logn` just gives you `n`.

Comment: oh btw...if there is a series with a lot of terms, do we just pick the highest degree term and say that is the Big O estimate